# Disable peek in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to disable the ctrl-click 'peek' feature in Visual Studio Code? Ideally I'd like ctrl-click to just open the file containing the definition in a new tab.

**Edit**: I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31046) to at least make it less confusing. Apparently my terminology is slightly wrong.

To clarify, there are two actions:

1. Right-click -> **Peek Definition**
2. Right-click -> **Go to Definition** (bound to ctrl-click)

Their behaviour is as follows:

1. PD, Single Definition

   - Opens inline interface showing definition.
2. PD, Multiple Definitions

   - Opens inline interface showing definitions.
3. GtD, Single Definition

   - Open the file containing the definition.
4. GtD, Multiple Definitions

   - Pick one of the definitions at random, open that file, *and* an inline interface showing all the definitions.

All of those are fine except the last. Doing both things results in a really redundant and confusing UI like this:

[image: Confusing!]

There should be a way to have one of these behaviours:

- Pick one of the definitions at random, open that file.

Or:

- Open inline interface showing all the definitions (*in the current file*)

Comment: Upvoted you, but your issue on gh its not related with "ctrl-click just open the file containing the definition in a new tab" (I mean, disable it). I've opened a new issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34755).

Comment: @Matt, what is exactly that you want? Do you want to disable peeks completely? Or you want multiple reference to open in peek window instead of the first reference?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I realized after playing with it more that I there is multiple stuff. First, there is a bug in the Flow JavaScript support where multiple definitions are displayed while they are the same. That's of course out of scope for this question.

For this bounty, I would say that I would accept something that disable peek showing up if VSCode already opened the other file and that tab contains both definitions. I understand if definition are in two separates files, randomly picked them does not make that much sense.

Hope I'm clearer and sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @Matt, This would need code modification at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/e499dc62b581c67e329c49c91187316221b2d2f3/src/vs/editor/contrib/goToDeclaration/goToDeclarationCommands.ts#L129 so I can't propose an answer with code change but give you a direction as this requires rebuilding vscode

Comment: Specific VS Version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've made a pull request to fix this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/68023, but until then here's a temp fix that patches the VSCode installation files. You'll need to re-apply every update.

#### EDIT:  The fix was merged into vscode. It should be in later versions.

With this fix Ctrl+Click will:

- Use peek if there are multiple definitions
- When using peek, will not navigate to the best match in the editor and cause you to lose your spot
- If there is only one definition, it will navigate to the best match and NOT open peek.

---

1. Figure out what the function that needs to be patched looks like. The method is `DefinitionAction.prototype._onResult(editorService, editor, model)`

   - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/e82d8bb6e6c8fd07ca16eacd16663ebd221187cb/src/vs/editor/contrib/goToDefinition/goToDefinitionCommands.ts#L128
2. Go to the VSCode installation directory. `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` and right click and open the directory in VSCode so that we can use VSCode's search feature to search for text in every file.
3. Search for `_onResult` and evaluate every result, checking to see if the signature and body matches what we are expecting from the function we saw in step 1.

   - We know from step 1, the function `_openReference` is nearby. Use that to narrow the search.
   - I found it in `workbench.main.js` line `2454`. Use bracket matching to find the end or know that it ends immediately before `t.prototype._openReference`
   - The function when formatted is the following (async func is compiled down to statemachine, that's why it looks nothing like the source typescript):

     ```
     t.prototype._onResult = function (e, t, r) {
       return i(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
         var i, s, a;
         return n(this, function (n) {
           switch (n.label) {
             case 0:
               return i = r.getAriaMessage(), o.alert(i), this._configuration.openInPeek ? (this._openInPeek(e, t, r), [3, 3]) : [3, 1];
             case 1:
               return s = r.nearestReference(t.getModel().uri, t.getPosition()), [4, this._openReference(t, e, s, this._configuration.openToSide)];
             case 2:
               (a = n.sent()) && r.references.length > 1 ? this._openInPeek(e, a, r) : r.dispose(), n.label = 3;
             case 3:
             return [2]
           }
         })
       })
     }
     ```
4. **Replace the function with the following** (if using same version) or format and edit the function you found to be similar to this example. Note the `o` variable is the global\window object and subject to change.

   ```
   t.prototype._onResult = function (e, t, r) {
     return i(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
       return n(this, function (n) {
         switch (n.label) {
           case 0:
             return r.getAriaMessage(), o.alert(r.getAriaMessage()), this._configuration.openInPeek || r.references.length > 1 ? (this._openInPeek(e, t, r), [3, 3]) : [3, 1];
           case 1:
             return [4, this._openReference(t, e, r.nearestReference(t.getModel().uri, t.getPosition()), this._configuration.openToSide)];
           case 2:
             r.dispose(), n.label = 3;
           case 3:
           return [2]
         }
       })
     })
   }
   ```
5. Launch VSCode. You will get a `Your Code installation appears to be corrupt. Please reinstall`. Just hit the gear icon and click `Don't Show Again.`

Answer (score 2):

I tried to find a workaround changing the behavior of <kbd>CMD</kbd> + Click to go to implementation but it appears there is no solution yet?

The VSCode documentation shows its set by default to go to definition without a way to modify it:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved

On my machine (Mac) if I press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + Click or <kbd>F12</kbd> on a method it will direct me to the Peek view on the definition, however <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> will direct me to the implementation without the peek appearing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed in a newer version. If I now hover over `FOO` in `foo.cpp`, I see the normal tooltip `#define FOO 2`. If I press Ctrl, the message expands to add the text "Click to show 2 definitions" and if I click while still holding Ctrl, I get the peek window, as requested.

[image]